# Dictionary and session + C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to use a dictionary to hold the values of file upload control. Users can upload a total of 5 documents. One document at a time. I have used C# and ASP.NET. I have tried the below, but I am not sure how to add the dictionary data  to viewstate. 
// Declaration of Dictionary

```
private new Dictionary<string, string> AttachmentNames
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["AttachmentNames"] != null)
                {
                    return (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["AttachmentNames"];
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Dictionary<string, string>();
                }
            }

            set
            {
                Session["AttachmentNames"] = value;
            }
        }
```

Every time the file is uploaded, I want to add the filename , file path to the dictionary.

I have kept a loop to check the file item count and based on that I am adding the files to dictionary. Code as below:

```
if (!hlAttachment1.Visible)
                {
                    hdnAttachment1.Text = this.GetFilePath(fuAttachment);
                    AttachmentNames.Add(fileName, hdnAttachment1.Text);
                 }
                else if (!hlAttachment2.Visible)
                {
                    hdnAttachment2.Text = this.GetFilePath(fuAttachment);
                    AttachmentNames.Add(fileName, hdnAttachment2.Text);
                  }
// like this till 5
```

Since the data is not added to viewstate, everytime the file is uploaded, only the last file is getting added to dictionary. How to add the dictionary to view state and utilize it to add items to dictionary. Now, on every post back the data is lost. How to add and update the dictionary data to view state?
Thanks

Comment: You're using ViewState in 2017?  May the great spaghetti monster have mercy on your soul.

Comment: I would not use `ViewState` to preserve data  in this case. Instead use `Session`. `ViewState` is sent with the HTML and visible to the client, it also needs to be serializable and can cause a lot more traffic. Session is stored in server memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the property can be simplified as such. This optimization allows the state of the session variable be completely managed in the property simplifying the callers code. This code should be compatible with your calling code.

```
private new Dictionary<string, string> AttachmentNames
{
    get
    {
        /* may want to lock if multi threads is a possibility */
        if (Session["AttachmentNames"] == null)
            Session["AttachmentNames"] = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        return (Dictionary<string, string>) Session["AttachmentNames"];
    }
}
```

This code is creating a property that references a session variable. Note that there's only a get accessor on this property, there is no set to simplify things.

When we access this property, the get accessor checks the Session variable to see if it's been initialized (is not null). If it hasn't been initialized (is null) it sets the session variable to a new dictionary.

The second part of the accessor simply returns the session variable, casting it to a dictionary.

The beauty of this code is that it abstracts the session management to the property.

If your code is only adding/updating values, you can use the property as such.

```
AttachmentNames[fileName] = hdnAttachment1.Text;
```

Note that the fileName is the key to the dictionary.

Check the documentation for more info on dictionaries.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi, How to add the Dictionary to the session?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. When the file is uploaded, how to add the file name, file path ( I have the values of file name, file path in the string) to the dictionary and session?

Comment: Hi, In the first code block, which I have provided there is a "If" block. So on every if, else if  - I just need to call AttachmentNames[fileName] = hdnAttachment1.Text; then followed by in the else if AttachmentNames[fileName] = hdnAttachment2.Text; will this now store both the values?

Comment: @venkat14 If the fileNames are different then both values would be set. If the fileNames are the same than the 2nd call would overwrite the first value.

Answer (score 1):

> add the dictionary data to viewstate

Ehh, that seems a bad idea. The view state is encrypted and put in the HTML. That content send back and forth on every request. So if you upload a 100MB file, every request and response with have a size of at least 100MB...

A better storage location is the `Session` object, where you can save the uploaded files for the time being. If necessary, you can put the key of the file in the view state, so you can always relate it back to the stored file in the `Session`.

Comment: Hi. I have updated the code to Session. How to add the dictionary data to session

Comment: Also the file size is not more than 2 MB/file

Comment: And only the file name, path are stored. Not the whole file.

Comment: But still, where do you save the content then? Is was on the request, but after than one is done, you lose it.

Comment: content is saved when the submit button is clicked. I have taken care of that. I want to add the filename, file path ( filename, file path - I already have ) in the dictionary and add it to viewstate / session , so that the data is not lost in postback